# Insert in RMySQL from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sql-insert, rmysql

Im trying to add data to MySQL table by using RMySQL. I only need to add one row at a time and it's not working. What I'm trying to do is this.

```
dbGetQuery(con,"INSERT INTO names VALUES(data[1,1], data[1,2])")
```

so what I'm doing is that I have values in data frame that is named as "data" and I need to put them into mysql table. before that I will check them if they are already in the table or not and if they are not then I will add them, but that way it isn't working. The data is read from .csv file by `read.csv` .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `paste` to construct that actual query.

```
dat <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
query <- paste("INSERT INTO names VALUES(",data[1,1], ",", data[1,2], ")")
query
#[1] "INSERT INTO names VALUES( 1 , 3 )"
dbGetQuery(con, query)

# If there are a lot of columns this could be tedious...
# So we could also use paste to add all the values at once.
query <- paste("INSERT INTO names VALUES(", paste(data[1,], collapse = ", "), ")")
query
#[1] "INSERT INTO names VALUES( 1, 3 )"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try with:

```
dbWriteTable(names, data[1,],append=True)
```

as the [DBI package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf) details