# Store rows from a dataframe in a database

Tags: mysql, r, sql-insert, rmysql

I have a dataframe that I would like to upload to a cloud environment. Im already connected to the database and now would like to "write away" the records.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
#df
a  b
1 3 11
2 4 12
```

And try to add it to the table "team" on the server like this:

```
 #connect to database (conection is called "con")

 for (i in nrow(df)){

  var1 <- df$a[i]
  var2 <- df$b[i]
  players_home <- dbGetQuery(con, "INSERT INTO team VALUES (var1, var2)")

 }
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
  Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Unknown column 'var1' in 'field list'
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your columns for an insert statement

[Some instructions here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) 
VALUES (value1,value2, value3,...)
```

You should also use `paste` otherwise `r` assumes your passing a string as argument. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073929/insert-in-rmysql-from-data-frame)

In your case, assuming that your values match the column numbers, it would be

```
query <- paste("INSERT INTO team VALUES(",var1, ",", var2, ")")
players_home <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
```

Comment: `sprintf` also can be helpful.