# Connecting R shiny with mysql , mysql being running in rds (AWS)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny, amazon-rds, rmysql

Firstly i want to connect shiny app with mysql in rds(AWS).
After connecting shiny with mysql i want to store my shiny output in database
so that once my output is generated i don't need to compile my program again i can retrieve the data from my database.
After searching deeply in google i get following script to get data

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
ui <- fluidPage(
 textInput("ID", "Enter your ID:", "5"),
  tableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$tbl <- renderTable({
conn <- dbConnect(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "shinydemo",
  host = "shiny-demo.csa7qlmguqrf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  username = "guest",
  password = "guest")
on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM City WHERE ID = '", input$ID, "';")
dbGetQuery(conn, query)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am not getting any helping script to store my output data in my database.
Any help please.

Comment: Have you looked here? Stackoverflow is full with very good examples of what you want to do. . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073929/insert-in-rmysql-from-data-frame

Comment: What if i am not using dataframe